# How do I stop Xamarin.UITest removing data between Tests?

Tags: c#, xamarin, uitest, xamarin.uitest

I have written some `UITests` for my `Xamarin` application using `Xamarin.UITest` I am trying to split my tests into individual Tests but sometimes the tests I run remove the previous data and my application goes back to the start-up proccess.

I have added the `Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear` attribute to the StartApp but this does not work all the time:

```
app = ConfigureApp.Android.ApkFile(PathToAPK).WaitTimes(new WaitTimes()).EnableLocalScreenshots().StartApp(Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear);
```

When does `UITest` clear the application data and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok So the setting the setting `Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AppDataMode.DoNotClear` in the `StartApp` method does stop your application clearing the data in between tests.

But If you change your application and rebuild it then the new application will overwrite the old one clearing the data,

Or if you run the `Xamarin Test Recorder` this will also wipe the data.

Which makes developing these tests horrendous!

Comment: Got the same problem. The App is, when starting for the first time, downloading a huge amount of data. Currently the app is doing this everytime I lunch a test. This isn't quite good ...